# Shift+Enter does not work in Facebook postings

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, help, javascript

When writing text/posts on facebook in Tor, I cannot use shift+Enter to create a blank space to the next line of text.

shift+Enter, only enters my posting.

If that can't be fixed, how do I put some air between lines, for easier reading?

Comment: Do you use https://facebookcorewwwi.onion for Facebook or another URL? Do you use Tor Browser? Which version?

Comment: I assume that the latest version was installed a few weeks ago. I don't know what "corewwwi.onion is, or where to find it. 
As I said, the problem occur's when writing the fb posts in Tor. 
When posting, using my old Chrome browser, or any other browser, I have no problems creating space between lines by using shift+Enter, when posting on facebook.
In Tor the post is published right away and without any spacing between lines.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a general issue with keyboard input handling not being handled correctly, there's already a [bugreport about it](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/20800) (currently unresolved) in the Tor bug tracker.
I can also confirm it doesn't only affect facebook, but all pages which have different behaviour for Shift+Enter compared to just Enter.

This also means the issue has nothing to do with the level you set the security slider of the Tor Browser to.

Comment: The site in the bug report works perfectly fine in TBB 7.0a3. Which version do you use?

Comment: I'm still on the stable track, so 6.5.2. I was able to reproduce this issue with Twitter (DMs), Facebook and Cryptpad.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Facebook in different ways:

- https://facebook.com is the usual URL you can use with any browser. Facebook loads several other ressources when you open this URL. It might be that the security settings in Tor's Browser prevent some from being executed. Thatswhy <kbd>Shift+Enter</kbd> does not work.
- https://facebookcorewwwi.onion is an URL which works over Tor Onion Services. Every connection stays inside the Tor network. If you open this URL in Tor Browser, you can use Facebook and <kbd>Shift+Enter</kbd> works. This is probably because the ressources are executed.
- Facebook App runs on several mobile phones. You can set it up to work with Tor (if Tor is installed on your phone) and I bet you can also insert line breaks here.

Comment: Looking at the permissions requested by the Facebook app, Tor might not help much in keeping you anonymous. Here are some permissions the app requests: "retrieve running apps", "find accounts on the device", "read your own contact card", "read calendar events plus confidential information", "read your contacts", "precise location (GPS and network-based)", "read your text messages (SMS or MMS)", "read call log", "read phone status and identity", "read the contents of your USB storage", "take pictures and videos", "record audio", "view Wi-Fi connections", "read Google service configuration"

Comment: My Tor security settings are already at the lowest. What else can I do?

Comment: I prefer writing in facebook on my computer. It's more convenient and I'm mostly at home, anyway.

If I can't make it work, I'll probably have to go back to Chrome again, since it's annoying to read long posts without spacing.

Comment: Why do you think that you can't use Facebook on your computer?